# Age Verification with jQuery.AJAX using dropdown fields?

Tags: jquery, ajax, onchange

I'm setting up a registration page and looking for a clean solution to perform a jQuery age check using the AJAX method ***by the onChange event and already before submitting the form***. I have a simple form (shortened):

```
<form action="" id="birthday_form" name="birthday">
    <select name="field_4_1">
    <option value="0">[ DAY ]</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    </select>
    <select name="field_4_2">
    <option value="0">[ MONTH ]</option>
    <option value="1">January</option>
    <option value="2">February</option>
    <option value="3">March</option>
    </select>
    <select name="field_4_3">
    <option value="0">[ YEAR ]</option>
    <option value="1982">1982</option>
    <option value="1981">1981</option>
    <option value="1980">1980</option>
    </select>

<div id="result_of_age"></div>

<input type="submit" name="submit_birthday" value="Send" />

</form>
```

I know how to get the result into the prepared DIV with jQuery.ajax() + "serialize" when submitting the form, but I am looking for a solution to already show the result as soon as all 3 selection fields are set.
I'm sure it's possible, but which way would be the best solution to solve this?

Any ideas?

Best regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('select', '#birthday_form').on('change', function() {
    var day  = $('[name="field_4_1"]').val(),
        month  = $('[name="field_4_2"]').val(),
        year = $('[name="field_4_3"]').val(),
        age = 18,
        birthdate = new Date(),
        currdate = new Date();

    if (day!='0'&&month!='0'&&year!='0') {
        birthdate.setFullYear(year, month-1, day);
        currdate.setFullYear(currdate.getFullYear() - age);

        if ((currdate - birthdate) < 0){
            $('#result_of_age').text('You are not old enough to join');
            this.form.onsubmit = function() { return false; }
        }else{
            $('#result_of_age').text('You are old enough to join');
            this.form.onsubmit = function() { return true; }                
        }
    }
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/8W76k/3/)
    ​

Comment: Your code is working so far, but I have also other 'select' elements in this form and I still need to POST the values to the ajax.php script to perform the age validation. As result in the DIV I need something like "You are old enough to join". In the ajax.php I will do a check if the date entered is valid at all and if the person is over 18 years old. If so, I want to allow submitting the form and continue the registration steps.

Comment: @Carlos - just saying what it is you're after in the question is a good idea, and I've updated my answer again?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a data-* attribute to the selects to track their ready status. When a selection is made, set to true and check the status of the other selects. When the 3rd one is set and all three are true, do your call. Basically, it's like tumblers in a lock.

```
$(this).attr('data-ready', 'true'); // in onChange handler

function IsFormReady() {
  If ($('selOneId').attr('data-ready')==='true' && //same with other 2 selects){
    YourAjaxCall();
  }
}
```

Comment: Okay, this seems to be the part to check if all 3 selection fields are set, but how do I send the the data to the ajax.php file to return directly the result into the DIV before submitting the form? Can you give an example regarding the code I've provided?

Comment: Are you saying to validate the date? Just validate it in the JavaScript. Try parsing into a Date object (if it works, its valid) and then subtract it from today's date and see if the difference is 18 years.